# Is it ok to consume from multiple queues inside one NodeJS process?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I have a process thats supposed to handle two different kind of messages and process them similiarly but differently.

Naturally I would use two seperate queues for both kind of messages and call consume() twice.

The other possibility would be to just have one queue and differ by some kind of "message type" property inside the content buffer and handle each message in a switch case.

Which would be the more "recommended" way of doing this?

Are there any advantages/disadvantages when using any of the two approaches?